# Why does Ubuntu work so well on my Thinkpad T495?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, thinkpad

I am using Linux for some months now on my new Lenovo Thinkpad T495. In the last months, I have had problems with different distributions. For example with Xorg which crashed quite often, I did not get sounds working on Manjaro, have had problems with WiFi and some of my FN keys did not work. Now I switched to Ubuntu and everything worked from the beginning. I did not have to troubleshoot anything. Keys, sound, etc. worked.

My general question is:

Why is this so different from other distributions. Why does Ubuntu work well right after the installation and why did I have so many issues with Fedora, Manjaro, or Debian? What does Ubuntu do which "the others" don't want or cannot do?

It would be nice to hear some different opinions.

Comment: Because it is the Windows of Linux distributions, they have more resources to make it more compatible with more hardware.

Comment: There's the question of working out-of-the-box, and then the issue of continuing to work without problems.  Ubuntu comes bundled with an extensive collection of drivers and good utilities for automatically installing the right ones.  Debian typically requires initially selecting the version that includes proprietary drivers, and setup is less automated.  Manjaro is pretty good about bundled drivers.  Fedora is primarily a test bed for Red Hat. and sometimes has problems with drivers.  Once you're up and running, Debian (stable) will be the most problem-free of these (cont'd)

Comment: (but not user-friendly for novices).  If you stick with Ubuntu's LTS versions, you will rarely have critical errors, but a lot more minor bugs than Debian (newer but less-tested apps and features).  Manjaro is a rolling release and updates breaking things isn't uncommon (it's user-friendly until things break; then you're working with its Arch foundation, which isn't for novices).  Fedora is on par with Ubuntu interim releases; it isn't intended as a stable distro, it's intended to weed out problems before things go into the stable distro.